# Loading html from assets if no internet connection

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to make a webview where the app loads a HTML page from assets if there is no internet connection. I have been following this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044856/how-do-i-display-no-internet-connection-popup-and-an-html-page-when-internet-is) and i have made a `CheckNetwork.java` but where shall i put this code below into my **MainActivity**? I am a beginner at this so please explain as simple as possible.

```
if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this)) 
  {
   // do something
  }
```

This is my **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

WebView browser;
private ourViewClient mClass;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mClass = new ourViewClient(this);

browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvwMain);

browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

browser.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient(this));
try {
    browser.loadUrl("http://MyWebPage");
}

catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

  }

}
```

Comment: put it in your oncreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this)) 
   browser.loadUrl("http://MyWebPage");
} else {
   browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_html.html");
}
```

I am also including example of how you load a html from your assets.

Comment: I made it work, thanks. I also had to include permission to `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` in my manifest which i had not done. What was the function of the code `catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();` ?

Comment: @EreckTaut: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Comment: You can also load from R.raw.

Comment: @Mgamerz difference being that the raw resources will not be compressed when shipped in the apk. As for the solution proposed - the OP explicitly asks about the assets solution.